# PureInput in redux form example

Tags: redux, redux-form

In the [Deep Form example](http://redux-form.com/5.2.5/#/examples/deep?_k=e34uy5), the author adds a `PureInput` component to the mix. While creating a component I intend to use in multiple forms, I followed along and used a `PureInput`:

```
render() {
    const { emailList } = this.props
    return (
        <div>
          <label>Enter Email Addresses</label>
            <PureInput type="text" placeholder="user@domain.com" field={emailList} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However, I flipped the control over to a normal textbox and things continued to work normally:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="user@domain.com" {...emailList} />
```

Why would the author have used this custom `PureInput` in his example?

```
class PureInput extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.field !== nextProps.field
  }

  render() {
    const { field, ...rest } = this.props
    return <input {...field} {...rest}/>
  }
}

PureInput.propTypes = {
  field: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default PureInput
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as the author, I can tell you. Basically, I was struggling to improve the performance of that form, and was trying different techniques, none of them were successful because the performance problem was inherent in the design of `redux-form` `v5`, which is why `v6` got written from the ground up to use a better architecture.

Your conclusion is correct, the `PureInput` component in that example is almost totally useless.

Comment: Ah, I see! I'll look forward to the `v6` production release. Thanks for your efforts on the library, it's helped solve a number of complex problems for me in the few weeks I've been using it.